# Heroku not loading bundler for non-web ruby app

Tags: heroku

I have a program that I wrote using ruby. It doesn't have any web interface, but I use bundler for dependency management.

On my local system, running the app is as simple as typing `rake app:start`, and it loads up just fine.

When I deploy to heroku, however, my app crashes with a `cannot load such file -- bundler` error.

My Procfile looks has this entry `app: bundle exec rake app:start`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you push your app to Heroku, what does it say in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Heroku was not changing the GEM_HOME field to the vendor/bundle directory.

By adding the following config vars to Heroku, my app ran as expected:

```
GEM_HOME: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
PATH:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:bin:node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Adding these was done via the `heroku config:set CONFIG_NAME=VALUE` command.